# PHPUnit and Mock Objects not working

Tags: php, object, mocking, phpunit, stubs

I am not sure if I am doing something wrong or it is a bug with PHPUnit and mock objects. Basically I am trying to test if `$Model->doSomething()` is called when `$Model->start()` is triggered.

I am using Ubuntu in a VirtualBox, and phpunit 1.1.1 installed via pear.

The full code is below. Any help would be appreciated, it's driving me crazy.

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPUnit/Autoload.php';

class Model
{
    function doSomething( ) {
        echo 'Hello World';
    }

    function doNothing( ) { }

    function start( ) {
        $this->doNothing();
        $this->doSomething();
    }
}

class ModelTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    function testDoSomething( )
    {
        $Model = $this->getMock('Model');
        $Model->expects($this->once())->method('start'); # This works
        $Model->expects($this->once())->method('doSomething'); # This does not work
        $Model->start();
    }
}
?>
```

The output from PHPUnit:

```
There was 1 failure:

1) ModelTest::testDoSomething
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:doSomething> when invoked 1 time(s).
Method was expected to be called 1 times, actually called 0 times.


FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 1, Failures: 1.
```

Comment: I got it working, but i have had to pass the methods as an array.      `code` $Model = $this->getMock('Model',array('doSomething','doNothing'));
        #$Model->expects($this->once())->method('start'); # This works

Comment: Does anybody know why you have to specify the methods. Is this a configuration issue. Many examples of using mocks does not state you have to specify methods.

Comment: Did you really mean phpUnit 1.1.1? Latest is 3.7, and the earliest you're likely to encounter in a supported linux distro is phpUnit 3.4 or so.

Comment: Sorry my bad, not sure where I got the 1.1.1 from, i am using the version 3.6.12. Thanks to everybody for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found, you need to tell PHPUnit which methods to mock. Also, I would avoid creating expectations for methods that you are calling directly from the test. I would write the above test like this:

```
function testDoSomething( )
{
    $Model = $this->getMock('Model', array('doSomething');
    $Model->expects($this->once())->method('doSomething');
    $Model->start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on why David Harkness's answer works, if you do not specify the $methods parameter to `getMock` then *all* functions in the class are mocked. Incidentally, you can confirm this with:

```
class ModelTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    function testDoSomething( )
    {
        $obj = $this->getMock('Model');
        echo new ReflectionClass(get_class($obj));
        ...
    }
}
```

So, why does it fail? Because your `start()` function has been mocked too! I.e. the function body you have given has been replaced, and so your `$this->doSomething();` line never gets run.

Hence, when there are any functions in your class that you need to be preserved, you'll have to explicitly give the list of all other functions.